# Vuex action cancel promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, promise, vuex

I want to be able to cancel a started promise from my Vue component, specifically a promise returned by a Vuex action.

My use case is that my Vuex action polls an endpoint for status, and I want to be able to cancel that polling if the user performs a certain action (close function in the example).

I have created a custom CancellablePromise class lifted from another stackoverflow answer, but it isn't working with Vuex.

**Cancelable promise class** (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60600274/2152511)

```
export class CancellablePromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
  private onCancel: () => void;

  constructor(
    executor: (
      resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void,
      reject: (reason?: any) => void,
      onCancel: (cancelHandler: () => void) => void
    ) => void
  ) {
    let onCancel: () => void;
    super((rs, rj) =>
      executor(rs, rj, (ch: () => void) => {
        onCancel = ch;
      })
    );
    this.onCancel = onCancel;
  }

  public cancel(): void {
    if (this.onCancel) {
      this.onCancel();
    }
  }
}
```

**Action**

```
async [SomeAction.foo]({ state, dispatch, commit, rootGetters }) {
    const cancellablePromise = new CancellablePromise<any>((resolve, reject, onCancel) => {
      const interval = setInterval(async () => {
        const status = await dispatch(SomeAction.bar);
        if (status === "goodstatus") {
          clearInterval(interval);
          resolve();
        } else if (status === "badstatus") {
          clearInterval(interval);
          reject();
        }
      }, 2000);

      onCancel(() => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        reject();
      });
    });

    return cancellablePromise;
  }
```

**Component**

```
data: (() => {
  promise: undefined as CancellablePromise<any> | undefined
}),

async call() {
  this.promise = this.$store
    .dispatch(SomeAction.foo)
    .then(response => {
      // do something
    }) as CancellablePromise<any>;
},

close(): void {
  if (this.promise) {
    this.promise.cancel(); // outputs cancel is not a function
  }
}
```

The problem occurs in the `close` function where `this.promise.cancel` is not a function.

This *seems* to me is because the object returned by `dispatch` is indeed a Promise, not a CancellablePromise. My suspicion comes from looking at [the Vuex source](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js#L152) which, again, *seems* to create a `new Promise` from the `Promise` returned from the action. I'm not very familiar with Typescript's type system, but unless I'm misreading this code I think my `CancellablePromise` is "lost" here.

How can I accomplish what I want to do here?

Comment: i guess you can add it to prototype: `Promise.prototype.cancel = ...`?

Comment: As you pointed out, Vuex wraps your `CancellablePromise` with a new (non-cancelable) `Promise`, so you can't directly access your own promise from your action. I don't think there's a way to cancel the promise unless you patch Vuex yourself.

Comment: Do you propose to use `this.promise` for anything other than calling its `cancel()` method?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 No I don't think so. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Extentding Promise is messy and unnecessary. It's more normal

- to expose a Promise's `reject` method to the wider world (outside the Promise's constructor), and call it wherever necessary to cause the Promise to adopt its error path.
- to race a "cancellation Promise" against the Promise of interest but that's not necessary here as the promisification of the `setInterval` process makes a `reject` method available.

Something like this should do it (untested).

Action

```
async [SomeAction.foo]({ state, dispatch, commit, rootGetters }) {
    let reject_, interval;
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject_ = reject; // externalise the reject method
        interval = setInterval(async () => {
            const status = await dispatch(SomeAction.bar);
            if (status === 'goodstatus') {
                resolve();
            } else if (status === 'badstatus') {
                reject(new Error(status)); // for example
            } else {
                // ignore other states ???
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
    promise.cancel = reject_; // decorate promise with its own reject method.
    return promise.always(() => { clearInterval(interval) }); // clear the interval however the promise settles (resolve() or reject() above, or promise.cancel() externally).
}
```

Component

```
data: (() => {
    cancel: null
}),
async call() {
    this.close(new Error('new call was made before previous call completed')); // may be a good idea
    let promise = this.$store.dispatch(SomeAction.foo); // don't chain .then() yet otherwise the .cancel property is lost.
    this.cancel = promise.cancel; // store the means to force-reject the promise;
    return promise.then(response => { // now chain .then()
        // do something
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
},
close(reason): void {
    if (this.cancel) {
        this.cancel(reason || new Error('cancelled'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the same reason as my original solution doesn't work: `dispatch` creates a `new Promise` which wraps the `Promise` created in the action. Maybe I'm doing something wrong which makes not work though?

Comment: Ouch! That makes life tricky. I wonder if there's some other way to dispatch; a way in which `Someaction.foo()` is called directly?